# How to properly import a SBT project to IntelliJ

Tags: scala, sbt, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to import this simple project to IntelliJ:
https://github.com/Codemunity/akkahttp-quickstart
I cloned the repo, and used "File -> Open" to open the project in IntelliJ.

Unfortunately, I get `Extracting structure failed` and IntelliJ seems not to recognise that my `build.sbt` is a sbt file (it highlights all sbt statements in red).

[image: IntelliJ not parsing the sbt.build file]

In fact I cannot import any sbt project that I download from GitHub. But on the other hand I can create a simple "hello world" project myself and I do not have any such problems with this.

What to do to import this project?

Comment: Hi :) What java version do you using currently? I tried to import with jdk 15 and it seems to don't work. With jdk works straightforward instead..

Comment: I am using open-jdk 15, so should I try with another version?

Comment: In the screenshot you shared, click on the different red exclamation matk icons: the 1st one will likely contain more details about why importing the SBT project failed

Comment: Yes @Nexon, you should try with JDK 11. 
Sorry, but in the first comment, I forgot to write the correct java version. Let me know if with different JDK the import project works :)

Comment: @GaëlJ I just get the "Cannot resolve symbol" errors repeated twice for each statement

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi When I tried to use the JDK 11 version (corretto), the problem persisted, but when I switched to JDK 1.8 it suddenly started working. I thus deduct that the problem has it's roots in the sbt vs. jdk compatibility. When launching the sbt console with JDK 11, I can read that the SBT version is  0.13.18. Maybe it's too low? Since I found that there are higher SBT versions as 1.4.1, however they seem to be tied to the JDK version, so it is weird that there are compatibility issues (I am a newbie to SBT, so I don't how exactly this works).

Comment: Maybe I should update SBT in some way to make it work with higher versions of JDK?

Comment: Yes, it is another possibility :) to change the sbt version you should go in project > build.properties.
Here, there is an entry like : `sbt.version = ...`. If you use the last version (1.4.1) no error going to be thrown :)

Comment: SBT 0.13.x is quite old, you should target 1.3.x at least now (1.5.4 being latest as of now)

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: @BorisAzanov Windows